# I would that & I would to God / heaven

Tags: grammar, subjunctive-mood

> For I *would that* all men were even as I myself. (1 Corinthians 7:7)
>
> I *would to* God my name were not so terrible to the enemy as it is.
>   (2H4 I.ii.219-220)

Do these *would*-constructions mean the same thing?

Comment: Related: [“Would” with a present meaning—is this correct?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19591/would-with-a-present-meaningis-this-correct)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Would* in both cases indicates a desire or intent, but the Shakespearean instance is more forceful.

I'm no [hermeneutician](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/), but the Corinthians verse opens with *θέλω*, which is straightforwardly translated as *I want* or *I wish*. Merriam-Webster lists this use of *would* as archaic, whereas OALD simply calls it "[literary](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/would#would__194)":

> **would that…** (literary): used to express a strong wish

References to God (or the devil) intensify. *Would to God [that]* on its own can stand as an old-fashioned interjection, and in such cases the *would* cannot always be directly substituted with *want* or *wish* (*How I hoped she would leave him. Would to God!*).

Comment: +1 - this answer is more instructive than mine. I didn't realize (duh) that God was an intensifier.

Comment: @PatrickCălinescu I couldn't say, although I found at least one version of the text that has *θελω γαρ*, which would suggest optative, but then it should be *θελει*, I think… I haven't thought about ancient Greek in almost 20 years, so this is already straining my memory. Don't quote me :).

Answer (score 2):

The verb *will* in the past meant *wish*. This sense is mostly lost in contemporary speech, but can be seen in the saying "where there is a will there is a way".

The modal *will* we normally use today, is related to this old sense, but still different.

This old sense of *will* is similar to (and cognate with) the Latin *volo, volere*, which you probably have in Romanian as well.

In terms of what the above sentences mean, you could read them as:

For I *might wish* that all men were even as I myself. (1 Corinthians 7:7)

I *wish* to God my name were not so terrible to the enemy as it is. (2H4 I.ii.219-220)

If you're translating these to Romanian in your head, use the subjunctive.

Comment: I don't see why it can't be used in the plural.

Comment: Oh, so sorry. Yes, just as *phrase* can be plural: there are several phrases in that sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they mean the same thing: they express a "wish". If you substitute *wish* for *would*, you will see the construction clearly.

[*would*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/would) vb.: (one meaning) I wish: *Would* that he were here.

You can see it in another (slightly) familiar phrase

> Would that I could, but I can't, so I shan't.

This form implies a wishful or idealized alternative to an undesired reality. In other words, the speaker wishes for a different set of circumstances or outcome than the real situation he or she is in, and is called The subjunctive mood.

The [subjunctive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood) is a grammatical mood found in many languages. Subjunctive forms of verbs are typically used to express various states of unreality such as *wish, emotion, possibility, judgment, opinion, necessity, or action that has not yet occurred* – the precise situations in which they are used vary from language to language.

It is an older form in English, used less frequently today, but seen often enough in early translations of the Bible and other early writings, as well as very formal writing.

Comment: A rattlesnake is a poisonous snake with scales at the end of it's tail modified to form a rattle. When the snake is threatened and about to attack, it shakes it's tail (it rattles). *Eloquent speech* is powerful, persuasive, expressive and effective. So is the rattle of a rattlesnake - no one who hears it doesn't know that there is a great danger in proceeding. :)

Comment: @PatrickCălinescu: I'm confused: "Interesting proverb you've got there". Rattlesnake? Where does Susan, or anyone for that matter, mention a proverb here with a rattlesnake in it?

Comment: @Mitch - on my profile: "There is nothing as eloquent as a rattlesnake's tail." (Native American proverb, Navajo)